# How to get appicon programmatically from sdcard/storage .apk file?

Tags: android, appicon

Using `ApplicationInfo` i'm already tried and it works well but it is shows only installed app's appicon. but i want to get appicon from file path(.apk file) programmatically.

```
Drawable icon=applicationInfo.loadIcon(getPackageManager());
```

I want to get appicon from apk file. this file is already stored in storage.

so is there a way to get icon/thumb from .apk file for showing appicon programmatically ?

Comment: what exactly you are trying to do? do you want to show your application's icon or other application's  or apk icons that are in the sd card??

Comment: yes @sourabhkaushik exactly i want to show only appicon programmatically from .apk file path

Comment: @pskink that is wrong

Comment: @VladyslavMatviienko yes indeed, nice to know...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can get that info from APK file:

```
 String apkPath = "path/to/apk/file.apk"; 
 PackageManager packageManager = context.getPackageManager();
 PackageInfo packageInfo = packageManager.getPackageArchiveInfo(apkPath, 0);

 // you need to set this variables manually for some reason to get icon from APK file that has not been installed
 packageInfo.applicationInfo.sourceDir       = apkPath;
 packageInfo.applicationInfo.publicSourceDir = apkPath;

 Drawable icon = packageInfo.applicationInfo.loadIcon(packageManager);
```